# Memory allocation/deallocation in Java

Tags: java

I am a beginner at java. Assuming that I declare a variable of type Account

```
Account _account = new Account("Thomas");
```

and then somewhere else later I do something like this:

```
_account = new Account("George");
```

what will happen to the memory slot to which variable _account was allocated in the first statement? Is it going to be automatically reallocated? Is this operation going to have any costs memory-wise? Thank you.

Comment: The original `new Account("Thomas")` will be left headless (no references to it) and eventually get removed by the garbage collector.

Comment: t o begin with java use a java naming conventions.

Comment: The GC will clean it up and the cost is very small, most likely far less than you need to worry about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are no references to the old object, then it will be garbage collected automatically. (Or, more accurately, it will be available for garbage collection and the memory will be automatically reclaimed when the garbage collector gets around to it.)

The above is true if you don't assign the original `_account` reference to anything and simply overwrite it. However, if you do something like this:

```
Account _account = new Account("Thomas");
List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
accounts.add(_account);

_account = new Account("George");
```

then the old object still has a reference (indirectly) through the `accounts` list. As long as  it is possible to reach the original object in some way from any live variable in your code, then it won't be subject to garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

The "memory slot", as you call it, will become eligible for garbage collection. That means that you can no longer access it, and it will be removed from the memory sooner or later.

The operation of allocating a new object with `new` has an implied cost (besides possible computations that are done in the constructor). Cleaning up unused references also has an implied cost, because it creates work for the garbage collector. But this is the nature of object-oriented programming. Unless your whole work does not only consist of allocating new objects, this should not be an issue. If it *is* an issue, then there is most likely something else wrong with your program.